# a tangent vector which does not fall on any geodesic

Tags: riemannian-geometry, geodesic

Given a point on a manifold, is it possible that there is a tangent vector at that point which does not correspond to any local velocity of  some geodesic? That is in that direction no geodesic exists whatsoever? If the answer is positive what is a condition which assures the above does not happen at a point? That all tangent vectors correspond to some geodesic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given any point $p$ and $v \in T_pM$, there is a unique geodesic $\gamma$ starting at $p$ with velocity $v$, meaning $\gamma(0) = p$ and $\gamma'(0) = v$. This is a consequence of the theory of ODE's. Since every tangent vector is tangent to a point, we can use the above to conclude that the answer to your initial question is *no*.

Comment: OK. additional question: the geodesic are second order ODEs correct? you are saying given the first order condition, solution always exists. But it is not enough to make a unique right?

Comment: The *point* and the *tangent vector* are the two initial conditions, @alireza. (It becomes a first-order differential equation up on the (unit) tangent bundle; there a *point* gives both pieces of information.)

Comment: @Ted Shifrin 1 oh right thanks!